# sshfs: permission denied when trying to access specific folder

Tags: mount, directory, sshfs, ls

I can access to my specific folder like this:

```
ssh -YX  xxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx
cd ../the/folder/I/want
```

or with an absolute path

```
ssh -YX  xxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx
cd /the/absolute/path/to/the/folder/I/want
```

However I can't `ls`it from my distant home directory

```
ssh -YX  xxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx
ls ../the/folder/I/want 
-> ls: cannot access ../the/folder/I/want: No such file or directory
```

I can mount and access to my home folder with sshfs.
However, if I try to mount the specific folder with sshfs, for instance:

```
sshfs xxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx:/the/absolute/path/to/the/folder/I/want   ~/mountpoint
```

I can see the mounted folder, but I have no permissions to access it.
This is the result of `ls -l` local command:

`d---rwx---   1 root   wheel   4,0K  4 nov 22:46 mountpoint`

Is there a way to mount this specific folder?

Comment: sudo sshfs -o allow_other  xxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx:/the/absolute/path/to/the/folder/I/want   ~/mountpoint doesn't wotk either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of permission. The issue was finally resolved when the administrator gave me all permission on the distant folder.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when there are folders that only give access to specific groups. Then sshfs can fail to see that one of the IDs in that group belongs to the user that mounted the drive.

You just have to add the option "-o defer_permissions", e.g.

```
sshfs -o defer_permissions xxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx:/the/absolute/path/to/the/folder/I/want   ~/mountpoint
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options#default_permissions-and-defer_permissions?